# Can we estimate the error $\left| \frac{1}{N^2} \sum f ( \{ \sqrt{2} m + \sqrt{3} n \} ) - \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \right|$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, analytic-number-theory, na.numerical-analysis

As a computer experiment I did a few Riemannian sums to see if I could quantify the density statement $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})} = \mathbb{R}$ :

$$ \Big| \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{0 \leq m,n \leq N} \{ \sqrt{2} m + \sqrt{3} n \}^5 - \frac{1}{6} \Big| \stackrel{?}{<} \frac{1}{N^2} $$

A log-plot shows the correct exponent is a bit less than $2$.  Is it a Hausdorff dimension of some kind?

[image]

The general quantitative statement looks like some error term to an average:

$$ \Big| \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{0 \leq m,n \leq N} f \big( \{ \sqrt{2} m + \sqrt{3} n \}  \big) - \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \Big| \stackrel{?}{\ll} \frac{1}{N^2} $$

This is certainly false... what might the a good exponent be?  The statement could be more general - I have some kind of totally real number field - but then we get a worse exponent.

Comment: I think you can get an upper bound by standard bounds for the relevant exponential sums combined with the Erdős-Turán-Koksma inequality.

Comment: @GHfromMO this is vanilla [discrepancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence#The_Erd.C5.91s.E2.80.93Turan.E2.80.93Koksma_inequality) theory full.  the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Tur%C3%A1n_inequality) article has a statement that's somewhat hard to read.  I also notice their use of measure theory.   In a way, I'm just asking to work out the Discrepancy upper bound in that case of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and I gave a hint how to work out an upper bound.

Comment: "A log-plot" ... of what, exactly?

Comment: @GregMartin the horizontal axis is $N$.  The vertical axis is the log of the (absolute value) of the error term.

Comment: I suppose that the constant implied by the $\ll$ notation will depend on $f$. But then again, you haven't placed any restrictions on $f$, except, implicitly, that it's integrable. If $f$ is 1 at all points of the form $m\sqrt2+n\sqrt3$, and 0 elsewhere, you're out of luck. Maybe you're assuming $f$ is continuous.

Comment: this numerical experiment could have been done by a freshman. the quantitative equidistribution statements sometimes require $f$ is smooth. i have chosen $f(x)=x^n$

Answer (score 5):

From Koksma-Hlawka inequality (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence#The_Erd.C5.91s.E2.80.93Turan.E2.80.93Koksma_inequality)), the following holds for functions with bounded variation in Hardy-Krause sense.

If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x,y)=f(\{x+y\})$ is bounded variation in Hardy-Krause sense, then $$
\left|\frac1{N^2} \sum_{0\leq m,n \leq N} f(\{\sqrt 2 m + \sqrt 3 n\})-\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right|\leq C V(g) D_{N^2}
$$
where $C>0$ is absolute, $V(g)$ is the Hardy-Krause variation of $g$, and $D_{N^2}$ is the discrepancy of the double sequence $\{(\{\sqrt 2 m\},\{\sqrt 3 n\} ) \  |  \ 0\leq m,n\leq N\}$.

As @GH from MO suggested, Erdos-Turan-Koksma inequality gives an upper bound of $D_{N^2}$. The crucial estimate here is the bound of $||x||$ the distance between $x$ and its nearest integer, for certain numbers $x$.

Let $1\leq H\leq N^2$, we have
$$\begin{align}
D_{N^2}&\ll \frac1H + \sum_{h_1<H, \ h_2<H} \frac1{h_1h_2} \frac1{N^2}\left|\sum_{m\leq N, \ n\leq N} e^{2\pi i (h_1 m\sqrt 2 +h_2 n \sqrt 3)}\right|\\
&\ll \frac1H+ \frac1{N^2}\sum_{h_1<H} \frac1{h_1 \| h_1 \sqrt 2 \|} \sum_{h_2<H} \frac1{h_2 \|h_2\sqrt 3\|}
\end{align}
$$

If $\alpha$ is an irrational number with bounded partial quotients in its continued fraction, then 
$$
\sum_{h<H} \frac1{h\| h\alpha\|} \ll \log^2 H.
$$
Since $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ both have bounded partial quotients in their continued fractions, we have
$$
D_{N^2} \ll \frac1H+ \frac1{N^2} \log^4 H. 
$$
Taking $H=N^2$, we obtain 
$$
D_{N^2} \ll \frac{\log^4 N}{N^2}. 
$$